# How do I write a Django query where the left side of my WHERE condition is a math expression?

Tags: python, sql, django, python-3.x, where-clause

I'm using Django, Python 3.7, and PostGres 9.5.  I have a model with the following fields ...

```
class DomainTrackerStat(models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        ...
    num_negative_articles = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    num_positive_articles = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
```

I want to write a Django query that says give me all the objects whose condition match this PostGres WHERE clause

```
WHERE num_negative_articles / (num_negative_articles + num_positive_articles) > .95
```

However I'm having trouble writing the Django query expression because normally it only allows for a single field, e.g.

```
DomainTrackerStat.objects.filter(num_negative_articles__gt=.95)
```

How do I write this more complex query?

Comment: annotate before filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F() expressions can be used to execute arithmetic operations (+, -, * etc.) among model fields, in order to define an algebraic lookup/connection between them.

> An F() object represents the value of a model field or annotated column. It makes it possible to refer to model field values and perform database operations using them without actually having to pull them out of the database into Python memory.

```
data = DomainTrackerStat.objects.annotate(result=F('num_negative_articles') / (F('num_negative_articles') + F('num_positive_articles'))).filter(result__gt=0.95)
```

Now every item in data has an extra column named 'result' which contains the product of 'num_positive_articles' and 'num_negative_articles' divided by 'num_negative_articles' of each item respectively.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) for further reference

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the value of the mathematical expression in your queryset, and then filter by that annotate value:

```
DomainTrackerStat.objects.annotate(value=F('num_negative_articles') / (F('num_negative_articles ') + F('num_positive_articles'))).filter(value__gt=0.95)
```